# How to get next value when a common variable is increment in a parallel foreach?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I have a common variable that is updated inside a foreach, it is a counter, so I would like to get the next counter to be assigned inside a parallel foreach.

I have something like that:

```
int myCommonCounter = 5;
Parallel.Foreach(myList, (iterator, state) =>
{
    if(iterator.MyProperty == X)
    {
        iterator.Position = miCommonCounter;
        miCommonCounter = miCommonCunter + 1;
    }
});
```

I want to avoid gaps in property iterator.Position and avoid duplicates too.

I have seen an example that does the sum of partial results, [for example in this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd997393(v=vs.110).aspx), but it is not really the same case that I need.

So I would like to know if there are any away to update a counter to avoid gaps and duplicates when I updated inside the parallel foreach.

Thanks.

Comment: [`Interlocked.Increment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.increment)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The overload of Parallel foreach that has 3 parameters for lambda argument has counter already](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783359(v=vs.110).aspx).

You should use that instead of writing manual counter. It does not have duplicates. It wont have gaps either unless you stop loop for some reason.

```
Parallel.ForEach(source.Where(x => /*condition*/), (x, state, counter) =>
{
     iterator.Position = (int) counter;
});
```

Note that counter is type of long so you have to cast it to int if Position is of int type

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Could you write an example?

Comment: The problem with this counter is, if i am not wrong, it is that the counter is increased in each iterator. However in my case I have to increase only when the condition is true.

Comment: You forgot linq Where! If this doesn't work, try Where ToList.